# Libre Baskerville regular embedded web font displays the letter "t" smaller than other lower case letters

Tags: css, webfonts

I used FontSquirrel to convert Libre Baskerville to a web font. This is the CSS I added to my WordPress theme:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'libre_baskerville';
    src: url('librebaskerville-regular-wf.eot');
    src: url('librebaskerville-regular-wd.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('librebaskerville-regular-wf.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('librebaskerville-regular-wf.woff') format('woff'),
         url('librebaskerville-regular-wf.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'libre_baskerville';
    src: url('librebaskerville-bold-wf.eot');
    src: url('librebaskerville-bold-wf.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('librebaskerville-bold-wf.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('librebaskerville-bold-wf.woff') format('woff'),
         url('librebaskerville-bold-wd.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The lower case "t" displays smaller than all other lower case letters, but only in Libre Baskeville regular.  The bold version displays correctly. Behavior is consistent across Firefox, IE and Chrome.
[image: Libre Baskerville with incorrect t]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug within the source you've got?
Have a look at google fonts and look for this particular one. This source has a version where "t" looks like it's supposed to.

[Link](https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Libre+Baskerville)

Comment: That was it! I changed my CSS to use the Google Font API and the problem went away. The problem must have come from FontSquirrel, either their copy of the font, or something they did in creating the web  font.